# formal smoothness for henselian thickening

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Assume that $A,I$ is an henselian pair over $R$ and $X$ is a smooth $R$ scheme. can we say that $X(A)\to X(A/I)$ is surjective? I know that this is true if $X$ is affine(or even quasi-projective) or if $(A,I)$ is local henselian But I'm not sure about the general case?

Comment: If X is quasi-separated, then this is true (there is a proof in Prop A.0.4 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.02162.pdf). I suspect quasi-separatedness might be necessary but I don't really know.

Comment: For the general case, see Proposition 6.1.1 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.06424.pdf) (published in Acta Math. Vietnamica).